# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DataFrame'

Tags: python, macos, pandas, visa, pyvisa

I am running Python 2.7.10 on a Macbook.

I have installed:
Homebrew
Python 2.x, 3.x
NI-VISA
pip
pyvisa, pyserial, numpy
PyVISA
Anaconda
Pandas
I am attempting to run this script. A portion of it can be read here:

```
import visa
import time
import panda
import sys
import os
import numpy

os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')    #clear screen
rm = visa.ResourceManager()
rm.list_resources()

print(rm.list_resources())

results = panda.DataFrame(columns=['CURR', 'VOLT', 'TIME'])
```

This is what is returned on the command line, below.

Note the line that says

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DataFrame'

```
(u'USB0::0x05E6::0x2280::4068201::INSTR', u'ASRL1::INSTR', u'ASRL2::INSTR', u'ASRL4::INSTR')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "k2280.py", line 14, in <module>
    results = panda.DataFrame(columns=['CURR', 'VOLT', 'TIME'])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DataFrame'
```

Any help or insight on this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: I assume you want to import `pandas` and not `panda`? And your line `results = ` should be `results = pandas.DataFrame(columns=['CURR', 'VOLT', 'TIME'])`

Comment: Okay, I am trying that now with Python 3 instead of Python 2

Answer (score 2):

It's `pandas`, not `panda`, so use `import pandas` instead. It's also common practice to import pandas as `pd` for convenience:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
```

Answer (score 1):

The module is called pandas not panda

python3 -m pip install pandas

import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame()

Comment: Yes, I tried using pandas before but it did not work. Let me try installing pandas again on Python3

Comment: If you want to stick to python2 then just use "python -m pip install pandas"

Comment: I think that just resolved it! Great thank you.

It's strange I am sure I tried that command before but it didn't work...

Answer (score 1):

Please read if you're new to python.
As I am also new to python since 2 days and going through the tutorial.
What I know is pandas are the packages we install in the python library to the machine we are using.
As I am new and I was practicing to import and use ***pandas.DataFrame*** I kept my *filename* as ***pandas.py***

And here is the error I was doing. I can't use pandas.py because the machine is assuming its module inside this ***pandas.py***

I changed the filename and it start working fine.

Few things to know if you're getting errors.

1. You are using ***pandas.py*** as filename, you need to change the file name
2. You are not importing pandas in the file and started working on its module
3. You are not using DataFrame in ***camel case***

I think these 3 things should be kept in mind to use DataFrame to avoid this error.